# Почему происходит ошибка "expected a {" в цикле for each?

Tags: c++, foreach

Не могу понять в чем проблема. Просто не компилируется данный код:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
int arr[] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 };

for each (int var in arr)
{

}
system("pause");
}
```

Ошибка компиляции:

> expected a {

Чего ему здесь не хватает?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Видимо это [нестандартный синтаксис `for each, in`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/for-each-in), реализованный в свое время в VC++ и VC++/CLI. Однако в стандарт С++ попал альтернативный синтаксис, который и следует использовать:

```
for(auto const & int: arr)
{

}
```

Comment: как раз разобрался с этим. спасибо. 
странно, что автор, который описывал встроенный for each, не указал о стандарте.

Comment: @DimaKhodan Может статья или версия компилятора были старые? Этот синтаксис появился еще до выхода нового стандарта.

Comment: в том то и дело, что март 18го года.

Answer (score 2):

в с++ `for each` это не конструкция языка а функция из стандартной библиотеки `STL`, которую следует использовать следующим образом в вашем примере:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int arr[] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 };

    std::for_each(arr, arr + sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]), [](int el) 
    { 
        std::cout << el << ' ';
    });

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: об алгоритме `for_each` я то знаю, но здесь дело в том, что это именно цикл.
Прочитал статью о фор ич цикле, и хотел попробовать пару примеров, но как у автора, она просто не работает.

Comment: @DimaKhodan то что вы прочитали там скорее всего эта функция `std::for_each`.

Comment: по вашему я не могу отличить встроенный фор от алгоритма?

Comment: @DimaKhodan я не знаю, но в вашем примере синтаксическая ошибка

Comment: @DimaKhodan если ваш компилятор поддерживает 11ый стандарт - используйте range based loop тоесть: `for (auto el: arr) {  ... }`

Comment: `sizeof` для определения размера массива - плохая привычка, потому что если случайно отдать туда указатель, все сломается. Лучше `std::end(arr)` или `arr + std::size(arr)`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat это здесь вобще не принципиально, не понимаю зачем вобще придираться к этому коду.

Comment: @ampawd А как вы определяете, принципиально или нет? Кто-то запомнит и станет использовать в своем коде, а потом случайно отдаст туда указатель, и у него все сломается. Зачем использовать небезопасный подход, если есть безопасный?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat под принципиальностью имел ввиду что суть ответа не меняется от этого `sizeof`

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, ваш компилятор не поддерживает приведённый вариант. И правильно делает, в общем, потому что это полный нестандарт.

Стандартный вариант записи (начиная с C++11) такой:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
int arr[] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 };

for (int var : arr)
  {

  }
}
```